# changing a normalised value with the distance of two bones

Tags: geometry-nodes

I Have a row of cubes on the x axis with two effector objects on each side of the x axis that I wish to control the cubes with.

I wish to create a falloff of size for the cubes based on the location and distance of the effector objects. Please see image below[image]

Everything in the middle that is outside of the effectors alwayts has a value of zero and everything on the outside of ther effectors always has a value of 1. Everything inbetween the effectors has a normalised value that is based on the distance of the two effectors on the same side .

I have reviously made this with drivers in an armature but wish to try it with geometry nodes.
[image]

any help is much appreciated. [image]

Comment: Can be done in B4.0 using a repeat zone or before in B3.6 using a simulation zone or chaining a custom group, or without repetition can be done by approximation (less accurate). The reason you need repetition for accuracy is that previous cubes scale affect next cubes positioning, which affects their scale which affects following cubes positioning… Though I remember I used some mathematical formula to reimplement Apple icon menu (which also involved sliding of the icons), have the code somewhere…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
I misunderstood the problem. Everything becomes even easier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Altough this looks promosing, I think this doesn't quite answer OPs question. They wanted *two* objects to control *one* falloff side: one to change the starting point, and one to change the end point, of the falloff.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the problem. My bad. It's just a matter of a slightly different mathematical formula.

Comment: The way I understood the problem, the empty space between the cubes should be equal everywhere - and this is why you would need some kind of a 'repetition' mentioned by me in the comment.